# Neo4J browser not connected to server

Tags: neo4j

I have the new (v2) Neo4J Browser installed and working on port 5000. But when I visit the browser, at the top of the page there is an orange bar saying "Disconnected from Neo4j. Please check if the cord is unplugged."

I installed Neo4J v2 with homebrew and obviously started in before going to the browser page. Is there a missing config step I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. As a temporary (!) workaround, uncomment the line

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

in the file neo-server.properties.